# How do you pipe a vim buffer through lpr?

Tags: vim

I want to print the buffer, and I do it this way:

```
:%!lpr
```

Which works, but it erases the buffer and I have to restore it with undo `u`. Is there a better way to print the buffer (or a range of lines in it)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
:%w !lpr
```

or, using builtin print command,

```
:hardcopy
```

Comment: Excellent! Using `:ha`, Neovim was not printing Greek letters. This solution worked (I added the `lpi`: lines-per-inch and `cpi`: characters-per-inch to jiggle my font size, and run it as a `PpP` command/shortcut, added to my `~/.vimrc`: `nmap PpP :%w !lpr -o lpi=8 -o cpi=14<CR><CR>`. Arch Linux, locale: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ...`